# Swift webview (osx) , scraping using xpath

Tags: swift, macos, xpath, screen-scraping

I am browsing to a website I need using webView and I want to be able to download the video from that site or at least open it in the browser at its location.

I am getting the javascript / html from the site

```
let doc = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.documentElement.outerHTML")
```

I have no idea how I can search for an xpath in swift, this is the xpath I need.

```
//*[@id="snagHtml5Player"]/div[2]/video
```

Unfortunately I cant seem to find much information on stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to see if there is an xpath built into it or if I need to find another way of scraping to get the correct xpath.

Comment: Do you really need to use xpath? You could access the element using the regular JS DOM. Or check out the NSXMLNode documentation for xpath info.

Comment: No I don't have to use it, I have very limited experience with scraping and it was the go-to for me in Python after hacking together something that worked. 

Would you be able to give me any examples or point me in the right direction of JS DOM ? (I haven't even heard of that before)